# React with Apollo returns process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

But I got:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
eval
node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!/var/www/play-with-grapthql/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/instanceOf.mjs:2
```

Can you tell me why and how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I dived into guide and found my error. I installed:

```
yarn add react-apollo apollo-boost
```

But in guide I must to install:

```
yarn add apollo-boost react-apollo graphql
```

When I added `graphql` - error gone.