# ReferenceError: process is not defined Module.../../../node_modules/graphql/jsutils/instanceOf.mjs

Tags: javascript, express, web, websocket, graphql

I am using graphql subcriptions for my project, it is an instagram clone and I am doing function to like or unlike post, I use `npx create-react-app` to create my client and I use `express` to make my server.

at the client side, I set up my `client` like that:

`src/apis/client.js`

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  split,
} from 'apollo-boost';
import {getMainDefinition} from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import {WebSocketLink} from '@apollo/client/link/ws';
const httpUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/graphql';
const wsUrl = 'ws://localhost:5000/graphql';

const httpLink = ApolloLink.from([
  new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {}),
  new HttpLink({uri: httpUrl}),
]);

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: wsUrl,
  options: {
    // connectionParams: () => {},
    lazy: true,
    reconnect: true,
  },
});

function isSubscription(operation) {
  const definition = getMainDefinition(operation.query);
  return (
    definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
    definition.operation === 'subscription'
  );
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: split(isSubscription, wsLink, httpLink),
  defaultOptions: {query: {fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'}},
});

export default client;
```

As you can see, I use both websocket and https connection. Previously, I use only http connection, and everything works perfectly.

This is my `server` side:

`app.js`

```
const {ApolloServer, gql} = require('apollo-server-express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(cors(), bodyParser.json());

const typeDefs = gql(fs.readFileSync('./schema.graphql', {encoding: 'utf8'}));

const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/graphql'});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
apolloServer.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);
const port = 5000;
httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

This is the error:

[image]

I tried to google but it looks like an shortage of something in the webpack.config file of React but I don't know webpack. Please tell me how to deal with it, thank you so much and have a good day

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue after installing an up to date version of a specific package. Was able to resolve the issue by deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and the running `npm install` again.

Comment: That did not work for me :( which package was the problem?

Comment: Don't remember. Could you show an screenshot of your error message?

Comment: I fixed it by `npm install apollo-boost`, somehow that fell off my install list

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue and was able to resolve it by upgrading the version of graphql dependency in package.json. My project was using very old version of graphql i.e "0.13.2" and I updated the version to "14.6.0".

Comment: I still face the same problem. Even after upgrading.

Comment: In any case this issue is related to installation of dependencies. You might want to check version of your dependencies. If you are using apollo with graphql then you can try solution posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861251/react-with-apollo-returns-process-is-not-defined

If nothing works can you share your package.json file ?